# Accessing camera in iframe on Firefox Android

Tags: android, firefox, iframe, web-deployment

I have a URL: A. https://a.name.com which has a iframe with URL: B. https://b.name.com

B contains a SDK which requires Camera and Microphone access.

B is embedded in A using the following line:

```
<iframe src={url} allow="camera;microphone" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" style={{ border: "0px" }}  >
</iframe>
```

Issue: While trying to open https://a.name.com on Firefox Android it asks me for camera and microphone permission but when I allow it does not turn the camera on.
Instead if I directly put https://b.name.com in URL bar it turns on the camera as expected.

The following error is displayed in the Firefox console in android:

`NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context`

SDK used in B: [Banuba](https://www.banuba.com/)

Firefox Android Version: 80.1.2

I do not face this issue while trying to access https://a.name.com using Chrome(v81.0.4044.138) on android or both Chrome(v84.0.4147.125) and Firefox(v79.0) on desktop.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this. As a work around I added all the files from B into A so the new address for B now is https://a.name.com/B and I'm using this in the iframe.